# Ajax/jQuery/PHP in IE9 but not IE 8 or less

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My jQuery/AJAX script posts to a php file in hopes of returning XML.  When I print if the data I get all the html source code returned and the xml is not properly parsed in IE 8 or less.  The code works in IE 9 and all other browsers.  If anyone has a suggesion to what is goin on or a solution to my problem?

jQuery:

```
$.post("load-content/", {type: "POST", img: placeholder, dataType: "XML", selection: $(this).html()}, function(xml)  {
                // format and output result
                // alert(placeholder+' && '+$(this).html());
                nshow = $("content", xml).text() ;
                $("div p.p2").html(
                    $("content", xml).text() 
                );
                alert("HERE IE 9+ "+xml.length);
            });
```

php:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["img"]) && isset($_REQUEST["selection"])) {
      $xml='<ratings><content>test</content></ratings>';
      echo $xml;
```

*FYI this code is being run in Zencart folder

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
There were two problems here.

1. As the above answer suggested there was a problem with headers.
2. Again as the answer above suggested there was a problem with the datatype... code for older IE browsers should look something like

   ```
   $.post("/load-content/", {type: "POST", img: showcase, menuv: aname}, function(response) { ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i think your problem is making the ajax call itself. You are using [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) but youre supplying the options hash as if it is [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). The two are different...

[`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) takes the url, data, callback and response type as the arguments. You are supplying a hash similar to the one you would supply to [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) as your second argument which is not what it wants.

If you are going to use [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) it shoudl look like this:

```
$.post("load-content/", {img: placeholder, selction: whatever}, function(), 'xml');
```

Additionally its not obivous what the contex of your call is... `this` may not exist unless this is inside an event handler or `jQuery.each` iteration so using `selection: $(this).html()` may not make sense.

---

Have you tried setting the proper header for your response and exiting immeadiately?

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST["img"]) && isset($_REQUEST["selection"])) {
      header('Content-type: application/xml');
      $xml='<ratings><content>test</content></ratings>';
      echo $xml;
      exit(0);
 }
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the headers are included in another file and I am trying to retrun xml.  So, if I change the dataType then I get everything but I need to either strip the headers from the response or some how sercomvent the headers from being included on the page and then use the xml header above.

Comment: Know how to strip headers from a php file or the AJAX response?

Comment: the easiest solution is probably to use the jQuery `text` data type and then manually create an xml dom in your callback... Otherwise youre going to have to go research the ZenCart documentation and see if there is a valid way to override the headers it wants to send. Since its ZenCart i doubt if this is possible which would mean you would need to modify core files which probably isnt a good idea.

Comment: I take that back... youre jsut using the worng paramters to `$.post` see my update.